# Django rest framework import data from one table to another

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am doing a django rest framework API for ios application. And currently, i am doing a function between user and family.
Let me explain my logic between these two tables.

- MyUser= current user (an account that can be use to login)
- Family = current user's family member eg:father mother (it is not an account, cannot be use to sign in)

What i am thinking right now is that if the current user's family wanted to create an account, is it possible to import the data from family table to user table for that family member to register ?

- MyUser : `userId`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `phone_number`, `identification_num`, `first_name`, `last_name`
- Family :`Id`, `userId`(foreign key to user table, cannot be null) , `familyId`(can be null, reason is to allow user to add family member that did not register an account), `phone_number`, `identification_num`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `relationship`

Example scenario :

- user sent invitation link to that family member(either by email or other social app, and it will import the data to the family member to register an account
- family member click on invite link
- redirect to register page with the detail from family table.
- If register success, insert the userId of that family member into familyId of family table.
- that family member account's family table will also update to have a family data with the current user.

Did i explain it clearly ? Sorry if it is not, you can tell me if it is not clear enough so i can try to make it clearer.
Is this kind of design good ? It seems like it has alot of flaw. 
Is it possible to import all that information into that invite register page ?

My partner have another idea, which is User and Relation table.

Relation table: `UserId`(current userId,foreign key to User table), `FamilyId`(family user Id, foreign key to User table), `Relationship`(eg: mother, father)

When user create a relation, if the family has no account, user will create a user with no username and password(however there is still userId, although i don't understand how this is possible since username and password is a MUST therefore my solution is the first 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('user.User',
                                related_name='relation_to_user',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RELATION = {
        0: u'father',
        1: u'mother',
        2: u'other',
    }
    relation = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATION.items())

class Family(models.Model):
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(Relation)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('user.User',
                                  related_name='family_from_user',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`user->MyFamily->MyRelations`,but this will waste storage space when you family has other real user.

I had wrote similar app backend with Django.I design like:
`Relations: from_user to_user relation`    `Family:users`,with this pattern you can save storage space but need calculate family relations by youself everytime.

Fake use can be create like:

```
   fake_user.set_unusable_password()
```

Comment: Sorry just to clarify this, i updated my table so to prevent confusion. I realise it is my bad for inconsistancy of my models. So for the ForeignKey, is it like this? `to_user = models.ForeignKey('MyUser.user', re related_name='relation_to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: What does the `models.ForeignKey('MyUser.user')` means ?(the .user part) As documentation only use the table models. eg :  `models.ForeignKey('MyUser')`

Comment: `models.ForeignKey('MyUser.user')` equal `from MYUser.models import user models.ForeignKey(user)`

Comment: In the `Relation` table , there is only 1 `to_user `. That field is the family's id ? Would'nt it need another foreign key to link to current user ?

Comment: Although, how do i do the import data from family table to relation table and MyUser table ?

Comment: what are you talk about? import data?where?